# Virtualenvwrapper not using project_home

Tags: django, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper on ubuntu. I added the following lines to the top of bashrc file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/myprojects
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

everething works perfect except that when I use django-admin start project command, the project gets created in my home directory not the directory I specified in bashrc file which is myprojects. 
shouldn't new projects be created in myprojects folder?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're running `django-admin startproject` in your home folder?  `django-admin` doesn't know anything about virtualenvwrapper and, unless you explicitly specify a folder, it creates the project in the current folder.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination

Comment: Also, to create a project that lives in `PROJECT_HOME` and is associated with a specific virtualenv, you can issue `mkproject ENVNAME`, as explained [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#project-directory-management). Note that this will create a *generic* project, not a Django project.